# Apache2 and PHP error logging

Tags: apache2, php, log

I've been running a local apache2 on a Ubuntu 12.02 LTS with the latest PHP version installed.
I do need to debug some WordPress code to find out why certain values are not set in the database.

I have enabled the apache2 logging as well as the WordPress log, but the apache2 file is almost empty and not all error thrown are recorded.
Is there any specific location and / or setting I should check?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.02 doesn't exist. Did you mean 12.04 or 14.04? Also, what's your problem exactly? If something is not set it doesn't have to be an error, it can also be a setting. Please add a bit more information.

Comment: Sorry, just mixed up with the two. It's 12.04. 

As for the "error", I'd like to see what sort of value are sent to the database. I have a specific problem with the Yoast SEO plugin that doesn't save any of the info in the Meta Box. 
Ideally I'd like to see a log with all the SQL query sent?

Comment: @AndreaMoro I'm almost sure that queries don't get logged automatically by themselves. Unless you are using a framework which does that for you, you need to manually log them yourself in the code.

Comment: @Dan any particular framework or something I can add without loads of troubles?

Comment: Since you are using WordPress, I don't think installing a framework is an option. But with a quick search I found [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-queries/) you can try it out. I have not tested it nor tried it before, so I can't tell you if it actually works or not. I would ask this on [wordpress.SE] though, if there isn't such question there already.